Ppi and image size re POD prints
I work at 600 ppi in Gimp. Image size ranges from 8 wide X 14 High inches to around 15 X 22 inches. I export them as png files for uploading to print on demand.
Are these settings ok for this usage ?
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

https://resources.printhandbook.com/pages/dpi-for-printing.php

600 dpi is generally overkill for photographic images. 300 dpi is usually considered sufficient.  What kind of images do you have? Are they photos, graphics, text?  Images containing graphics, or sharp lines or text may be better at higher resolutions of course.
